# Is there an equivalent for ".code32" and ".code64" in NASM assembly syntax?

Tags: assembly, nasm

In GAS (GNU assembler) one can write `.code16`, `.code32`, and `.code64`, to tell the compiler what code should be produced. Is there something similar in NASM (Netwide Assembler) available? I didn't found anything online unfortunately.

The only workaround I can think of is to have separate NASM files for each and compile each with 16/32/64 compiler flags.

Comment: Yes, through the `bits` directive.  Refer to the manual for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
bits 16 ; .code16
bits 32 ; .code32
bits 64 ; .code64
```